# Laravel model's custom method BadMethodCallException - tries to use workbench folder's vendor files?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I got a weird error when added a custom method to a model file as I have done often. From the routes file I queried the model but got "method not found" – from the error log it's shown that Laravel is using vendor files under workbench folder even though that workbench package is not related to this code in any way.

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $obj = MyModel::where('id', 1111)->get()->first();
    return $obj->toCustomFormat();
});


[2015-02-03 16:08:08] development.ERROR: exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toCustomFormat()' in /var/www/project/workbench/envision/mypackage/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2117
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__call('toCustomForm...', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->toCustomFormat()
#2 /var/www/project/workbench/envision/mypackage/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(913): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('toCustomForm...', Array)
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->toCustomFormat()
#5 /var/www/project/bootstrap/compiled.php(7459): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/project/app/routes.php(12): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('toCustomForm...', Array)
#7 /var/www/project/app/routes.php(12): MyModel->toCustomFormat()
#8 [internal function]: {closure}()
```

artisan dump under project root didn't help. How do you do that?

UPDATED:

The model's custom method is this:

```
public function toCustomFormat() {
    $this->to       = date(DateTime::ISO8601, strtotime($this->to));
    $this->from     = date(DateTime::ISO8601, strtotime($this->from));
    return $this->toArray();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `MyModel` class?

Comment: I have now updated the question as requested by @lukasgeiter - and there was typo in the route's code example (I have simplified the model's and it's methods name).

Comment: Do you have multiple `MyModel` classes so you might be dealing with the wrong class (that doesn't have this method) ?

Comment: Oh damn, it seems that either FTP has silently failed to save the updates or that I had twice the same file open.

Previously I saw that working so it was misleading to see the files under workbench folder on the logging... Was that because it tried to escalate searching for the method under workbench instead?

Comment: I honestly don't know... So it's working now?

Comment: It is :) I'll post an own answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a mix up with saving file via FTP. So the method was not in the model's file.

However it was misleading to see that Laravel tried to find the method under a package in workbench's folder, which has another vendor folder. Perhaps Laravel tried escalate searching for the missing method under that location when it didn't find it in the models folder.